# mysql union select where table1 field3 = table2 field5

Tags: mysql, select, union

I'm starting with mysql and I do not know how to solve something like this:

```
SELECT 
  table1.col1 AS A,
  table1.col3 As B
UNION
  table2.col2 AS C,
  table2.col5 AS D
WHERE
  table1.col4 = table2.col6

/*expected*/
A B C D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just say:

```
SELECT 
  table1.col1 AS A,
  table1.col3 As B,
  table2.col2 AS C,
  table2.col5 AS D
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN Table2 on TABLE2.col6=TABLE1.col4
```